# Tag Cloud per date range in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I extensively looked for a plugin or some function to display a tag cloud only for a range of posts, defined by date. For example, I need to create a tag cloud from posts added between February and Abril of 2012, but this settings has to be configurable.

Does anyone know if there is a plugin or an easy database query to do this?

Thanks

Comment: I thought about using the native wp_tag_cloud function and create some taxonomy with the native archive Wordpress functions, but I couldn't go further than this.